# Stop form from refresing/reloading if captcha is not validated

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, page-refresh

I'm trying to stop my form page from refreshing when the submit button is clicked and the captcha box is not checked but I can't manage to do that.

I've managed to make the form work well, have the errors for all fields and also the fields value to be remembered but I can't stop the page reloading and that is annoying as it goes back to the top of the page.

Any idea what it's missing or if it's something not right?
Thank you!

This is my html code:

```
                  <form method="post"  id="contactform" name="contactform" action="/contact">
                     <div class="textbox-1"><label for="name">Your Name *</label>
                        <input class="textbox" type="text" name="name" title="" 
                               value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''; ?>"
                           oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Enter Your Name')"
                           oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required>
                     </div>
                     <div class="textbox-1"><label for="email">Your Email *</label>
                        <input class="textbox" type="email" name="email" title=""
                               value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''; ?>"
                           oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Enter a Valid Email Address')"
                           oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required>
                     </div>
                     <label>How did you hear about us? (Not necessary, but we appreciate the effort.)</label>
                     <select name="where" class="dropdown" id="where" title="" >
                        <option value="-">Click to Choose...</option>
                        <option value="Google Search" <?php echo (isset($_POST['where']) && $_POST['where'] === 'Google Search') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>> Google Search </option>
                        <option value="Social Media" <?php echo (isset($_POST['where']) && $_POST['where'] === 'Social Media') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>> Social Media </option>
                        <option value="Forum" <?php echo (isset($_POST['where']) && $_POST['where'] === 'Forum') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>> Forum </option>
                        <option value="Recommendation" <?php echo (isset($_POST['where']) && $_POST['where'] === 'Recommendation') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>> Recommendation </option>
                        <option value="Other" <?php echo (isset($_POST['where']) && $_POST['where'] === 'Other') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>> Other </option><?php echo isset($_POST['where']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['where'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''; ?>
                     </select>
                     <br/><br/>
                     <label for="message">Your Message *</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="textarea" type="textarea" title="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Enter Your Message')"
                        oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required><?php echo isset($_POST['message']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['message'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''; ?>
</textarea>
                     <br/><br/>
                     <label class="container" >
                     <input name="terms" type="checkbox" <?php 
int !empty($_SESSION['terms']) && $_SESSION['terms'] == true ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>
                        oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please indicate that you have read and accept our Terms of Use and Privacy Policy agreements.')"
                        oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required>
                     </input>
                     <span> I have read and accept the <a class="content-link2" href="/terms">Terms of Use</a> and <a class="content-link2" href="/privacy">Privacy Policy</a> agreements. *</span>
                     <span class="checkmark"></span>
                     </label>
                     <label class="container">
                     <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" value="yes"  <?php print !empty($_SESSION['newsletter']) && $_SESSION['newsletter'] == true ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>>
                     <span>I want to receive e-mails about limited-time special offers.</span>
                     <span class="checkmark"></span>
                     </label>
                     <div class="clr"></div>
                     <br/>
        <div class="h-captcha" name="h-captcha" id="hcaptcha" data-sitekey="key" ></div>
                  
<?php if(!empty($errMsg)): ?><div class="errMsg" id="errMsg"><?php echo $errMsg; ?></div><?php endif; ?>
        <?php if(!empty($succMsg)): ?><div class="succMsg"><?php echo $succMsg; ?></div><?php endif; ?>
                     <div class="bot-cont"><button type="submit" name="submit" class="submit_button" value="Submit">SUBMIT MESSAGE</button></div>
                     <br/><br/>
<label>* required fields</label>            
                  </form>
```

And this is the php code:

```
<?php 
 
// hCAPTCHA API key configuration 
$secretKey = 'key'; 
 session_start();
if(!empty($_POST['terms'])) {
    $_SESSION['terms'] = true;
} 
else {
    $_SESSION['terms'] = false;
}
 session_start();
if(!empty($_POST['newsletter'])) {
    $_SESSION['newsletter'] = true;
} 
else {
    $_SESSION['newsletter'] = false;
}

  $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
 $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

// If the form is submitted 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
     
    // Validate form fields 
    if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['message'])){ 
         
        // Validate hCAPTCHA checkbox 
        if(!empty($_POST['h-captcha-response'])){ 
            // Verify API URL 
            $verifyURL = 'https://hcaptcha.com/siteverify'; 
             
            // Retrieve token from post data with key 'h-captcha-response' 
            $token = $_POST['h-captcha-response']; 
             
            // Build payload with secret key and token 
            $data = array( 
                'secret' => $secretKey, 
                'response' => $token, 
                'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] 
            ); 
             
            // Initialize cURL request 
            // Make POST request with data payload to hCaptcha API endpoint 
            $curlConfig = array( 
                CURLOPT_URL => $verifyURL, 
                CURLOPT_POST => true, 
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data 
            ); 
            $ch = curl_init(); 
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig); 
            $response = curl_exec($ch); 
            curl_close($ch); 
             
            // Parse JSON from response. Check for success or error codes 
            $responseData = json_decode($response); 
             
            // If reCAPTCHA response is valid 
            if($responseData->success){ 
                // Posted form data 
$email_to = "myemail";
    $email_subject = "Email Subject";
    $ip_address=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];$geopluginURL='http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$ip_address;$addrDetailsArr=unserialize(file_get_contents($geopluginURL));
    $country=$addrDetailsArr['geoplugin_countryName'];
     $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $where = $_POST['where']; 
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $message = $_POST['message']; // required
    $newsletter = $_POST['newsletter']; 
    $hcaptcha = $_POST['h-captcha']; // required
$terms = $_POST['terms']; // required
 
    $email_message = "Form details below.<br/><br/><br/>\n\n";
   
    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
    
    $email_message .= "IP: ".clean_string($ip_address)."<br/><br/>\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Country: ".clean_string($country)."<br/><br/><br/>\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."<br/><br/>\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Heard from: ".clean_string($where)."<br/><br/>\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."<br/><br/>\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Newsletter: ".clean_string($newsletter)."<br/><br/>\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."<br/><br/>\n";

      // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
      $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
      $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
      // More headers
      $headers .= 'From:'.$name.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";
      //send email
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    $succMsg = header("location: $site_url/thank-you");
            }else{ 
                $errMsg = 'Verification failed, please try again.'; 
            } 
        }else{ 
            $errMsg = 'Please complete the CAPTCHA.'; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        $errMsg = 'Please complete the CAPTCHA.'; 
    } 
} 
 
?>
```

Comment: Use JavaScript and AJAX to disable the submit button until the CAPTCHA is validated.

Comment: I'm a beginner to the coding part so I have no clue how to do that. I've tried a few javascript codes I found online and these worked partially. It didn't refreshed the page if captcha wasn't checked but the form wouldn't submit after the captcha was validated. If you can give me an example that would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `$(".submit_btn").prop("disabled", true)` to disable, change to `false` to enable.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. Added like you said <script>$(".submit_button").prop("disabled", true) </script> to the form page and tried with both true and false. With false it doesn't change anything, still refreshes page and with true the submit button doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Did you add JavaScript that changes it from disabled to enabled when the user solves the CAPTCHA?  I'm not going to write this for you.

Comment: Like I've said I'm a beginner to the coding part so I'm not sure how to make this work. I'll search the web for this method you gave to see if I can find some examples. Thank you.